# Excel: Text to number

Tags: excel

I have had some numbers read into Excel from an external program. These numbers are currently formatted as text (column J). I would like to convert these numbers from text format to number format (decimal) as shown in column K as an example. I have already tried different possibilities (e.g. using the function "Text in Columns" and "Custom Formatting") but so far it has not worked. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to replace full stops with commas for your regional settings.

Comment: Try `=NUMBERVALUE(J1,".")`

Comment: How does "*numbers read into Excel from an external program*" this happen?  Perhaps a change in this process, especially if it is coming from a text file, would be best instead of converting after the fact.

Comment: With my current programming skills, I have unfortunately only managed to get the numbers from my program into a text file. From the text file I then read them into Excel and would like to manually format the numbers there. I know that this is cumbersome. Thanks for your help (@all)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way - use Data | Text to columns. Accept the defaults and change the destination to column K:

[image]

Or click on the down arrow next to the error symbol and select Convert to Number to convert in-place.

[image]

Comment: OP would probably want to change the decimal-seperator under "Advanced" =)

Answer (score 0):

Use value function
like this in the formula bar
=value(jn)
note: n is the row number in which your values are present

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem.

=VALUE(J1) or =VALUE(J1)*1 could help

also =CONCAT("0";J1) and then remove 0 (lil complicated, but worked)